# jquery mobile pass data between one page solution

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

how can I pass the value of the first page to the third page in this example, without loading the whole page new. The link list in the second page will be generated from an ajax call with:

```
<a href="#location_view">
```

Im looking for something like this:

```
<a href="#location_view?id=4">
```

so if the pagesector #location_view is called it get the id of the location

http://jsfiddle.net/g5Umg/4/

Comment: you mean like this? check `href` of "location view" on next page. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/g5Umg

Comment: I've posted the wrong link, neglect demo in previous comment. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9FzU5/

Comment: hi omar, nice to see you here :D

no its like in the first example. my usecase is that a user searches for a branche in a city. after he sends his data of the city and branche he gets a listview of possible locations generated by a ajax call. so after he clicks on one entry of the listview he gets the full data of one entry. my problem is that I cant give the third #location_view page data from the listview

Comment: Hi :) is it possible to prepare a fiddle with dummy data. it can be achieved in many ways.

Comment: It looks more like this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FzU5/2/

Comment: you want to pass param from first to last page?

Comment: yes but without using external links.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MfBb5/